# Jbehave Serenity BDD How to run specific suite?

Tags: junit, bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Have a bdd project jbehave + serenity
By default I run the story tests this way: **/*.story in storyPaths

But i need to run **not** all stories and **not** specific story, i need to run specific suite(specific folder with all the tests inside).

```
default patch


project\src\test\resources\SuiteTest1

**SuiteTest1**\MainPage\Test1.story
                        Test2.story
                        Test2.story

            PaymentPage\Test1.story
                        Test2.story
                        Test2.story

project\src\test\resources\SuiteTest2

**SuiteTest2**\LoginPage\Test1.story
                        Test2.story
                        Test2.story

            ForumPage\Test1.story
                        Test2.story
                        Test2.story
```

In `SuiteTest**1**` and `SuiteTest**2**` have different tests, i have to run them at different times.

Tried to run:

```
SuiteTest2*/*.story

SuiteTest2.*/*.story

SuiteTest2.**/*.story

SuiteTest2**/*.story
```

But this not work, it can't find the stories.....

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `SuiteTest2/**.story`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-asterisk tells a path to locate the file specified in any subdirectory below the defined one, so:

```
SuiteTest2/**.story
```

would locate any file with the extension **.story** in any folder starting at folder **SuiteTest2**

Therefore, in your example, it will find all the story files in **SuiteTest2/LoginPage** and in **SuiteTest2/ForumPage** but it will **not** process any of the story files under the **SuiteTest1** folder.